# TCPDF Line Graph

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am trying to code a line graphic by using TCPDF. I collocated more than 30 blocks and I can add explanation parts under first 22 blocks. But I have to pass to the other page to add explanation parts for the other blocks. What is the reason of this?  I rotated Multicell by 180 degrees but to add the explanation parts I rotated Cell by 90 degress.
I am open for your solutions.

//Blocks creating code

```
 $pdf->StartTransform();
                        $pdf->Rotate(180);
                            $pdf->MultiCell(3, $icb7memnuniyet/2, ' '.$txt, 1, 'J', 1, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 40, 'T');
                            $pdf->StopTransform();

                            $pdf->StartTransform();
                        $pdf->Rotate(180);
                            $pdf->MultiCell(3, $icb8memnuniyet/2, ' '.$txt, 1, 'J', 1, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 40, 'T');
                            $pdf->StopTransform();
```

//Text creating code

```
$pdf->setCellPaddings(1, 1, 1, 0.2);
$pdf->setCellMargins(1, 0, 1, 0.6);

$pdf->StartTransform();
$pdf->Rotate(90);
$pdf->Cell(30,0,'1.a Göktimur bakım merkezinin bir üyesi olmaktan memnumum ?',0,1,'R',0,'');
$pdf->Cell(30,0,'1.b Yeni meslek seçecek olsam yine aynı mesleği seçerdim.',0,1,'R',0,'');

$pdf->StopTransform();
```

[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMOZZ.png)

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], an image of what it creates and what you'd expect it to create instead? I can't tell from your description what problem you're having there. Please, also read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: You can see the example I uploaded as an image.

Comment: I can't run the code that generates that example though, because it's not provided. Also, it's unclear whether that code fits the [mcve] criteria.